# templates and pointers to member functions

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to use and work with pointer to some member function and I also want to be able to call that (or other) member function back.
Lets say, I have headers like this:

```
class A{
  public:
  template<class T> void Add(bool (T::*func)(), T* member){
    ((member)->*(func))();
  }
};
class B{
  public:
  bool Bfoo(){return 1;}
  void Bfoo2(){
    A a;
    a.Add(Bfoo, this);
  }
};
```

and cpp like this:

```
main(){
  B f;
  f.Bfoo2();
}
```

I've got following error:

> main.h(22) : error C2784: 'void __thiscall A::Add(bool (__thiscall
>   T::*)(void),T *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded
>   function type' from 'overloaded function type'

I need to call A::Add from many classes (and send information about class method and its instance) so that's why I want to use templates

Using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0. What am I doing wrong? I cannot use boost.

Comment: Is this even possible? Assigning a method to a normal function pointer? I would use the stuff around `std::function` (C++11 standard) for this. But you can't, as you are restricted to use a crappy compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an address of function

```
a.Add(&B::Bfoo, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, right way to do what you need is to use inheritance, for example:

```
class A {
  virtual void Add() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
  void Add() {...}
}

class C : public A {
  void Add() {...}
}
```

So in your main you can do:

```
A* a = new B();
a->Add(); /* this call B::Add() method */
```